# A Question Regarding the Use of a Comma for a Quoted Question

Tags: punctuation, commas, questions, quotations

I'd like to ask for the community's opinion regarding the correct usage of a comma for a quoted question.

In a situation such as this, which of the two following sentences would be correct? The placement of the comma is the only difference, and I can't seem to pinpoint which one is correct.

> A popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your favorite color?," red is a color that is beloved by many.
>
> A popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your favorite color?", red is a color that is beloved by many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence, everything before the comma is a dependent and introductory clause. You could rephrase the sentence by dropping it completely and the sentence's essential meaning would still be retained:

> (A popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your favorite color?"), red is a color that is beloved by many.
>
> Red is a color that is beloved by many.

It takes the same type of construction as any other introductory clause:

> (Being quite popular), red is a color that is beloved by many.

---

Both US and UK styling would say that question marks come before the second quotation mark.

US styling would say that commas come before the second quotation mark;  UK styling would also say that they come before the second quotation mark *only if* the comma is part of the syntax of what's being quoted—otherwise they come after.

- US: "There's nothing in the study," he said.
- UK: "There's nothing in the study", he said.
  **However**: "There's nothing in the study," he said, "the living room or the kitchen." Here, the comma comes *before* the second quotation mark because, *without* the interjected narration, the sentence would be written as "There's nothing in the study, the living room or the kitchen." In other words, the comma would be part of the quotation regardless. (The serial comma is not typically used in the UK, so I didn't use it here.)

Question marks (and exclamation points) always come before the second quotation mark—even if they don't end the sentence itself.

So, that covers normal situations. Your example, however, is not quite normal because it actually involves the use of both a question mark (inside what is actually being quoted) and a comma (which punctuates the surrounding text).

While the answer provided by Shoe does indeed quote *The Chicago Manual of Style* (the 17th edition says the same thing), it fails to put it into a specific context.

In fact, *Chicago* specifically says to *omit* the comma inside quotation makes in the case of dialogue. It's only in the case of *titles* of work that this doesn't happen.

Here is *Chicago* 6.125:

> When a question mark or exclamation point appears at the end of a quotation where a comma would normally appear, the comma is omitted (as in the first example below . . .). When, however, the title of a work ends in a question mark or exclamation point, a comma should also appear if the grammar of the sentence would normally call for one. This usage recognizes not only the syntactic independence of titles but also the potential for clearer sentence structure—especially apparent in the final example, where the comma after *Help!* separates it from the following title. (The occasional awkward result may require rewording.)
>
> “Are you a doctor?” asked Mahmoud.
>
> *but*
>
> “Are You a Doctor?,” the fifth story in *Will You Please Be Quiet, Please?*, treats modern love.
>
> All the band’s soundtrack albums—*A Hard Day’s Night*, *Help!*, *Yellow Submarine*, and *Magical Mystery Tour*—were popular.

In the example given by *Chicago*, "Are You a Doctor" is in quotation marks not because it's spoken dialogue but because it's the title of a short story. (Book titles are italicized, but articles and short stories are given within quotation marks.) You can tell it's not a quotation because of the capitalization.

Your example sentence *is* quoted dialogue, and so it follows the *first* example given by *Chicago* where the comma would be omitted.

However, in your specific case, the comma also serves an additional syntactical function (that of following an introductory clause) where omitting it is perhaps as awkward as not omitting it.

Personally, I would keep the comma but put it after the second quotation mark—assuming I kept it at all. If I *didn't* keep it, I would rephrase the sentence so that there was no awkwardness:

> Red—a popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your favorite color?"—is a color that is beloved by many.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is problematic irrespective of the position of the comma. The subject of the sentence (the noun phrase *A popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your favorite color?"*) needs to be followed by a predicate (verb). Instead, we see another noun phrase (*red*) with its own predicate.

One possible amended version would read:

> A popular answer to the common introductory question "What is your
>   favorite color?" is red. (This is a color beloved by many).

As to the punctuation of sentences containing quoted questions, according to *The Chicago Manual of Style* (16th edition) the comma that should be placed within the speech marks. It gives this example (p344):

> "Are you a doctor?," the fifth story in *Will You Please Be Quiet,
>   Please?,* treats modern love.

As a British English speaker I would be inclined to place the comma after the closing quotation mark. But I can't find an authoritative source to confirm my preference.